# Subreport not showing data and show blank page c#.net

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7majr.png)I have windows form application in which I'm using crystal reports.In main crystal report I want to display sub report but when I try to that, it displays data of main-report but other sub report data is not displayed.I tried following code but doesn't work. Please help me with details either a code issue or Subreport link issue?

```
   {
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("packinglistreport", con);
                command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command1.Parameters.Add("@id1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4;
                command1.Parameters.Add("@contno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                command1.Parameters.Add("@season_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

                SqlDataAdapter da121 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("packinglistreport", con);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@id1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5;
                command.Parameters.Add("@contno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@season_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da12 = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("packinglistreport", con);
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command2.Parameters.Add("@id1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 6;
                command2.Parameters.Add("@contno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                command2.Parameters.Add("@season_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da122 = new SqlDataAdapter(command2);
                SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("packinglistreport", con);
                command3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command3.Parameters.Add("@id1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 7;
                command3.Parameters.Add("@contno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                command3.Parameters.Add("@season_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da123 = new SqlDataAdapter(command3);
                DataSet ds7 = new DataSet();
                packinvoicereportotto cr5 = new packinvoicereportotto();
                da121.Fill(ds7, "packinglistdt");
                da12.Fill(ds7, "packinglistdt1");
                da122.Fill(ds7, "packinglistdt2");
                da123.Fill(ds7, "packinglistdt3");
                if (ds7.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0 && ds7.Tables[1].Rows.Count == 0 && ds7.Tables[2].Rows.Count == 0 && ds7.Tables[3].Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data Found");
                    return;
                    }
                cr5.SetDataSource(ds7);
                Report re = new Report();



                re.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; 
                re.Text = "Packing List Report";
                re.Show();
                re.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr5;
                re.crystalReportViewer1.DataBindings.Clear();
                }
```

Comment: May you post a snapshot of your design? Main report and one of the subreports where you are sure there is data.

Comment: @heringer see in question.

Comment: Is there a link between the report and subreport?

Comment: yes i try to link P.K field but nothing happens.